# Cypher query to get shortest path between A and B that doesn't go through C, that isn't massively slow? Or recommend alternative to Cypher/Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I'm working with a graph that has thousands of nodes.  Say I have person nodes, and FRIENDS relationships between them.  e.g., gus-[:FRIENDS]-skylar

If I wanted to find the shortest friend path between hank and gus as long as they're not separated by more than 20 rels, I could do this:

```
START hank=node(68), gus=node(66) 
MATCH p = shortestPath((hank)-[:FRIENDS*..20]-(gus)) 
RETURN p
```

This works and is fast, even when the found shortest path is of length 10 or more.

But say I wanted to find a path from hank to gus that *does not* go through glenn?

The query I've tried is this:

```
START hank=node(68), gus=node(66), glenn=node(59)
MATCH p =(hank)-[:FRIENDS*..20]-(gus)
WHERE NOT glenn IN nodes(p)
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p)
LIMIT 1;
```

This works on very small graphs (30 or so people), but if there are 1000's...the JVM runs out of heapspace.

So I'm guessing Cypher finds *ALL* paths between gus and hank of length 20 or less, and then applies the WHERE filter?  It's clear why that would be slow.

In an abstract sense, this algorithm should be doable with the same big O runtime, because all that would change is that you check to make sure each node (as you search) isn't the one you want to avoid.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?  I'm pretty new to Cypher.

If this is not possible with Cypher, can you recommend some other database and graph language "stack"?

Thanks

Comment: There's also a `allShortestPaths` keyword (mind the 's' at the back). How does that influence the performance?

Comment: With Neo4j, I would recommend using the Traversal Framework API. Cypher is built on top of that, so it gives you much finer control over how the db is searched.

Comment: Can you use lambda filters on the path? `(hank)-[:FRIEDS * bfs (e,v | v.name != 'glenn')]-(gus)`
https://docs.memgraph.com/memgraph/reference-guide/graph-algorithms/
see also example 6 here https://docs.memgraph.com/memgraph/tutorials/exploring-the-european-road-network/

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the performance of the following query? The main difference is that it compares paths instead of nodes. I've added a direction in the paths as well, as that will speed up the query.

```
START hank=node(68), gus=node(66), glenn=node(59)
MATCH p = allshortestPaths((hank)-[:FRIENDS]->(gus))
WITH COLLECT(p) AS gusPaths, hank, glenn
MATCH p2 = allshortestPaths((hank)-[:FRIENDS]->(glenn))
WITH COLLECT(p2) AS glennPaths, gusPaths
WITH filter(x IN gusPaths 
            WHERE NONE (x2 IN glennPaths 
                        WHERE x = x2)) AS filtered
RETURN filtered
ORDER BY length(filtered)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This isn't returning any results, though thanks very much for the suggestion.  allshortestPaths still only finds paths that are of the shortest possible length.  Due to my lack of familiarity with Cypher, I can't tell from your recommendation whether you know that when I said shortest path from A to B that doesn't go through C, I'm not requiring it to be as short as the absolute shortest path from A to B (which may or may not go through C).  It may have to be longer to avoid C.  I'm beginning to think Cypher may not support this.